# Defined eq and neq in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm a complete beginner in Haskell. I need to define eq and neq.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
deriving (Show)

toInt :: Nat -> Int
toInt Z = 0
toInt (S n) = 1 + toInt n

toNat :: Int -> Nat
toNat n | n < 0 = error "Nats do not support negative numbers!"
toNat 0 = Z
toNat n = S (toNat (n-1))

instance Eq Nat where
(==) = eq
(/=) = neq
```

Didn't mean to post instance. Correct code below:

```
eq :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
eq a b =
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to define `/=` explicitly, because its default definition is perfectly good. There's also no real need for a special `eq` function—you can define `==` directly. Here's a template (with a hint!) to start off.

```
instance Eq Nat where
  Z == Z = ?
  S m == S n = ???
  _ == _ = ?
```

Comment: I had to make a slight edit, but I believe your answer still applies. I understand the first two parts, but what exactly does _ == _ mean?

Comment: @ntb457, `_` is a pattern that matches anything and binds nothing. `_ == _ = ...` is basically the same as `x == y = ...` but it explicitly says we won't use those values.